# QT Translator Issue

Tags: qt

I have recently started working with QT and am currently trying to get the QTranslator to work.

I am using Visual Studio 2022 and the QT Tools plugin with QT 6.4.1.
Attached the lines from main method.

```
QGuiApplication app(argc, argv);
QQmlApplicationEngine engine;
QQmlContext* context = engine.rootContext();
    
QTranslator* t1 = new QTranslator();
qDebug() << t1->load(":/i18n/assets/i18n/rm80eplus_de");
qDebug() << app.installTranslator(t1);
qDebug() << t1->tr("Reset");

QTranslator t2;
qDebug() << t2.load(":/i18n/assets/i18n/rm80eplus_de");
qDebug() << app.installTranslator(&t2);
qDebug() << t2.tr("Reset");
```

Both variants (pointer, without pointer) run without errors but the text is not translated. Instead of "Zurücksetzen" the output is "Reset.

Path to translation files are stored in a ressouce file.

[image]

I found many posts here about QT Translator but I do not see what I am doing wrong.

Comment: And you really have a translation in your ts/qm file with the context 'QTranslator' and the message to translate 'Reset'?

Comment: Thanks for soon response. 
I have taken the translations from an existing program, where QTranslator is not used.
I only have a context "Language". I will have a look at the QTranslator logic.

Comment: When you need another context then you have to use [QTranslator::translate()](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtranslator.html#translate)

Comment: Sorry for late response and many thanks for this tip - it works !